# va_arg(ap, unsigned int) when the argument is `signed int` and vice versa

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I have noticed that [7.16.1.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1.1p2) of the C standard does permit accessing a variadic argument using a type that's incompatible with the actual variadic argument type as long as the type given via `va_arg` differs from the corresponding actual variadic argument type only in signedness …:

> ... the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding
>     unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character
>     type.

*and* the value **is representable in both types**.

This last requirement stands in contrast with the strict aliasing rule on accesses through pointers. The rule permits accessing an object through a pointer whose target's type differs from the object's effective type only in signednedness and the rule does so without additionally imposing any requirements on the target object's value:

[6.5p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:88)
>
> - ...
> - type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the
>     effective type of the object,
> - ...

What is the rationale for this discrepancy? Why should differently signed `va_arg` accesses and not differently signed pointer accesses care about the value being representable?

Comment: If you will, the object that is being accessed is not the same object you pass in, but instead, a copy is made for the parameters. Furthermore, the result of `va_arg` isn't the parameter itself, but a copy thereof. So you never really alias the _same object_ under different types.

Comment: @KerrekSB I realize `va_arg` is not like a pointer access because `va_start` usually (x86-64) saves registers and then `va_arg` gives you a copy, but I'd still expect both cases (pointer accesses vs accesses of variadic arguments) to be treated the same.

Comment: I think it's because when you call a variadic function, the arguments undergo standard promotions.

Comment: @PSkocik: I see no basis for such an expectation. As I said, there's no way for _users_ to access the same object through different types, so I don't see a "discrepancy". The point of strict aliasing is not that type punning would somehow break something intrinsic, but that the implementation is allowed to assume that lvalues of different types use distinct storage. With va_args, the compiler can do whatever it wants, because _it_ is in control. The aliasing rule is about what the compiler is allowed to assume about *user* coe.

Comment: From [ANSI C Rationale](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c3.html#3-3): _In principle, then, aliasing only need be allowed for when the lvalues all have the same type.  In practice, the Committee has recognized certain prevalent exceptions: The lvalue types may differ in signedness.  In the common range, a signed integral type and its unsigned variant have the same representation; it was felt that an appreciable body of existing code is not ``strictly typed'' in this area_ To my reading, this means that reinterpreting was meant to be allowed only for objects holding values from the common range