# Given a memory address, how do I print the byte located at that address in C?

Tags: c

Still a novice to C and the different things I am finding online as to how this is done are confusing me.

I have an address converted to an unsigned long value in order to verify that something is at that address in /proc/self/maps.

Once verified, I want to print the byte that is at that address.

From what I am gathering, the address itself is simply a pointer to that byte, so I need to dereference the memory address to get the byte.

So if I wanted to print that byte as a hex number, it would simply be:

```
printf("%02x", *address)
```

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%02x", (unsigned)*(unsigned char*)the_address_as_an_integer_or_pointer);
```

**Explanation:**

If you want to fetch a value from an address, it needs a pointer type. So you cast to a pointer to a `char`. (Strict aliasing permits fetching any value through a pointer to a character type, other pointer types are more limited). Casting to `signed char *` would lead to sign-extension (undesirable if you want to print the value as an `unsigned`) so you cast to `*unsigned char`. Then you dereference (`*`).
Such a `*(unsigned char*)address` has type `unsigned char`, which gets promoted to `int` when passed through the `...` of `printf`. That usually works with `"%x"`, but to fully satisfy the standard, `"%x"` requires an `unsigned` and thence the final cast to `unsigned`.

Comment: Is the second cast necessary? `(unsigned)`

Comment: @FiddlingBits Pedantically yes (otherwise UB), practically no.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I believe the `printf` rules unfortunately require exact type/specifier correspondence. The `va_arg` rules are more lax -- you can pass a `signed` that's taken (with `va_arg`) as an `unsigned` as long as the value can be represented as an `unsigned` (my related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842848/va-argap-unsigned-int-when-the-argument-is-signed-int-and-vice-versa). (Very pedantically speaking, `printf` need not be implemented with `va_arg`.)

Comment: volatile is also needed especially if you want read it more than once\

Comment: @P__J__ Well, only if the memory is backed by special hardware or you're racing with a signal handler. Then, you could also be racing with another thread, and then not even `volatile` is enough.

Comment: @PSkocik see my answer and examples

Comment: @PSkocik usually people read specific addresses if there is something special.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define UCPTR(addr)   (volatile unsigned char*)(addr) 

printf("0x%02hhx", *UCPTR(address));
```

To prevent question why `volatile`?

```
#define UCPTR(addr)   (volatile unsigned char*)(addr) 
#define NVUCPTR(addr)   (unsigned char*)(addr) 

void foo()
{
    while(*NVUCPTR(0x4564));
}

void bar()
{
    while(*UCPTR(0x4564));
}
```

and the resulting code:

```
foo:
        cmp     BYTE PTR ds:17764, 0
        je      .L1
.L3:
        jmp     .L3
.L1:
        ret
bar:
.L6:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR ds:17764
        test    al, al
        jne     .L6
        ret
```

I think that the code is self explanatory

Can it be archived other way?
Yes, but not portable, for example:

```
void foo()
{
    while(*NVUCPTR(0x4564)) asm("":::"memory");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5Jkhp5

Comment: The second part is for the nitpickers ("why `volatile`?" for example). They can read assembler

Comment: "_Why `volatile`?_" isn't really a nitpick; it is a good question that even a non-expert might ask about. The assembly listing doesn't really answer the question on its own.